# Noobish issue, assigning a value to one that's already inherited from a parent div?

Tags: css

I've a parent div with it's opacity set to 0.35 and I've a child div inside of it with text. I'm attempting to assign the child div an opacity of 1. I'm assigning it as follows: `#halp{opacity:1}`. The child div's opacity is still set to 0.35, as if assigning an opacity value in a child is only dividing from it's parent opacity value.

[Here](http://cssdesk.com/qvB67)'s a more fluent example of the issue.

Any way to have an actual opacity of 1, and not just 100% of the parents 0.35?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`opacity` gets inherited (or more correctly, the child gets a *relative* opacity to its parent opacity. This means that if you set the opacity for the child to *1* it will have the same opacity as its parent, if you set it to *0.5* it will be *0.5 * [parent opacity]*, and so on).

### Solution

Use `rgba(r,g,b,a)` to set `background-color`, no `opacity` declaration needed:

```
#top { background-color:rgba(133,133,133,0.35); }
```

Comment: Thanks! Saw the rgb value before but never noticed it was extended with an alpha value